# I ran into this error while creating a discord bot. TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: javascript

I ran into this error when typing node . to start the program. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I just started coding. What's wrong with my code?

This is for a discord bot and I haven't seen anything online about this problem.

```
const discord = require ('discord.js');

var client = new discord.Client();

const token = 'E440dqHpTt1qTHw4iWB3VgXit7_tcUd4';

client.on ("ready"), () => {
    console.log ("ready!");

    client.user.setGame ("prefix tb")
};

const prefix = "tb"
client.on ('message', function(message) {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "hello")) {
        message.reply ("Hi! What's up?");
    }

});

client.login (token);
```

I thought the bot would start but instead I got this:

```
 throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
    at checkListener (events.js:54:11)
    at _addListener (events.js:205:3)
    at Client.addListener (events.js:263:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Discord Bots\tylerbot\tylerbot.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, it's a simple typo in your code.
Simply change :

```
// This
client.on ("ready"), () => {
// Should be
client.on ("ready", () => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `client.once` instead of `client =.on`
so it becomes

```
    client.once("ready", () => {
```

also never revel ur token its like password for ur bot, people can use ur bot and may bug it out

Comment: Your answer is not align with question. Also, you can give doc reference for using `clinet.once()` method.